# Unable to bridge two ethernet interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bridge

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks as follows

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
 iface enp0s3 inet dhcp 

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
  address 172.16.3.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 172.16.3.0
  broadcast 172.16.3.255

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 172.16.3.1
  network 172.16.3.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 172.16.3.255
  bridge-ports enp0s3 enp0s8
```

Also here is my `ifconfig -a` output

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8c:24:a6  
          inet addr:172.16.3.1  Bcast:172.16.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd00:1cab:c070:ac02:a1de:6a17:c002:5915/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2607:fea8:5df:fc3d:a00:27ff:fe8c:24a6/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe8c:24a6/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd00:1cab:c070:ac02:a00:27ff:fe8c:24a6/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2607:fea8:5df:fc3d:a1de:6a17:c002:5915/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29858 (29.8 KB)  TX bytes:30385 (30.3 KB)

enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8c:24:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.27  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12650 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4736518 (4.7 MB)  TX bytes:1455119 (1.4 MB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:97:d3:2c  
          inet addr:172.16.3.1  Bcast:172.16.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:545550 (545.5 KB)  TX bytes:250033 (250.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:174076 (174.0 KB)  TX bytes:174076 (174.0 KB)
```

However when I try to `ping -I enp0s8 192.168.0.1` I don't get any reply back. Also nothing shows up in tcpdump on enp0s3 interface. Can you please advise me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses must be placed only on the bridge interface, not on any of its constituent ports.

Comment: Can you please show me how the interfaces file will look like. I tried what you suggested but no luck. Perhaps I am missing something.